# how can i sum by Type A and calculate the percentage of value respectively?

Tags: r

```
Type  value 
 A   100     
 A   234  
 A   359  
 B   385    
 B   352   
 B   233
```

how can i sum by Type A and calculate the percentage of value respectively?
expected output:

```
Type  value Percentage
 A   100     14.43
 A   234     33.77
 A   359     51.8
 B   385     39.69
 B   352     36.29
 B   233     24.02
```

i use

```
d=aggregate(value~ Type, df, sum)
value/d
```

or

```
mutate(Percentage = value / sum(value))
```

but neither work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `base R` option is

```
df$Percentage <- with(df, 100 *value/tapply(value, Type, sum)[Type])
```

-output

```
 df
  Type value Percentage
1    A   100   14.43001
2    A   234   33.76623
3    A   359   51.80375
4    B   385   39.69072
5    B   352   36.28866
6    B   233   24.02062
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), value = c(100L,
234L, 359L, 385L, 352L, 233L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Type) %>% mutate(Percentage = value/sum(value) * 100)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Type [2]
  Type  value Percentage
  <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 A       100       14.4
2 A       234       33.8
3 A       359       51.8
4 B       385       39.7
5 B       352       36.3
6 B       233       24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ave` + `proportions` like below

```
transform(
  df,
  Percentage = ave(value, Type, FUN = proportions) * 100
)
```

which gives

```
  Type value Percentage
1    A   100   14.43001
2    A   234   33.76623
3    A   359   51.80375
4    B   385   39.69072
5    B   352   36.28866
6    B   233   24.02062
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), value = c(100L,
234L, 359L, 385L, 352L, 233L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```